# Get user's roles hierachy in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can any one provide the user table structure with user's roles hierarchy in SQL Server? It would be appreciated if the SQL query also to be given.

Users hierarchy must be like below...

```
                                   CEO
                                    |
                                   VP
                                    |
                       ----------------------------
                       |                           |
               Sales Manager 1                 Sales Manager 2
                       |                           |
              -----------------        ------------------------
              |               |        |           |          |
          Sales Person1      SP2       SP3         SP4        SP5
```

Comment: *"Need table structure with query"* I am not sure how this relevant here?

Answer (score 1):

**Roles table:**

```
RoleId 
RoleName
```

**Users table:**

```
UserId 
UserName 
RoleId
ManagerId
```

It depends on what you want in your query. A simple one would be something like this:

```
select 
u.UserName as UserName,
r.RoleName as UserRole,
ISNULL(m.Name, 'No Manager') as ManagerName,
ISNULL(mr.Name, '') as ManagerRole
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN Roles r on r.RoleId = u.RoleId
LEFT JOIN Users m on m.UserId = u.ManagerId
INNER JOIN Roles mr on r.RoleId = m.RoleId
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Can you provide a query?